# Set highlight recyclerview element clicked, but all highlighted at the beginning

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Good morning, I am looking to show N items in a RecyclerView, and that at the time of showing them all have alpha = 1.0, but when one of those elements is clicked they all have alpha = 0.4 except the one that had a click.

I already have implemented the logic that changes the alpha between the elements that are clicked, but i still need to find a way for everyone to start as alpha = 1.0.

Any advice?

```
class ServicesAdapter(
private val context : Context,
private var items: ArrayList<Entity.Service>,
private var listener: ServicesAdapter.OnItemInteraction
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ServicesAdapter.ListViewHolder>() {

private val TAG = "Audi-NewsInner"
private var isUser = false

private var row_index = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION

interface OnItemInteraction{
    fun onItemClicked(item: Entity.Service, containerView: View, position : Int)
}

init{
    val preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.appPreferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val accessToken : String? = preferences?.getString(Constants.accessToken, "")
    isUser = !accessToken.isNullOrEmpty()
}

fun setItems(items: ArrayList<Entity.Service>){
    this.items = items
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int
): ServicesAdapter.ListViewHolder {
    return ListViewHolder(
        (LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
            R.layout.cardview_services_enabled_one_element,
            parent,
            false
        ))
    )
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return items.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ServicesAdapter.ListViewHolder, position: Int) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder available Services started position==$position")
    val item = items!![position]
    holder.title.setText(item.name)
    if(BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE.equals("qa")) Utilies.handleImage(context, holder.image, item.cover?.replace("prod", "qa"), R.drawable.no_img)
    else Utilies.handleImage(context, holder.image, item.cover, R.drawable.no_img)
    //holder.image.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.service_line))
    handleClick(holder.itemView, holder.itemView, item, position)
    handleClick(holder.itemView, holder.image, item, position)
    handleClick(holder.itemView, holder.title, item, position)
    //holder.image.isSelected = (row_index==position)
    holder.image.alpha = if(row_index==position) 1.0F else 0.3F
}

private fun handleClick(containerView : View, mainClickedView: View, item : Entity.Service?, position : Int){
    mainClickedView?.setOnClickListener {
        containerView.isSelected = true
        item?.let {
            listener.onItemClicked(it, containerView, position)
            notifyItemChanged(row_index)
            row_index = position
            notifyItemChanged(row_index)
        }
    }
}

class ListViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
    val title : TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.nameElement)
    val image : ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageElement)
}
```

}

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tune your `if` logic in onBindViewHolder. It now sets the alpha to 1.0 if row_index is changed by click event, so you just need to add the default condition in there too:

```
holder.image.alpha = if(row_index==position || row_index==RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) 1.0F else 0.3F
```